# Keypad not working - Arduino Uno - Multiple errors to do with variables

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

Trying to make a keypad work on my arduino uno and I'm getting these errors:

```
 7SegDisKeypad:14:5: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 int 1 == A0;

     ^

7SegDisKeypad:15:5: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 int 2 = A1;

     ^

7SegDisKeypad:16:5: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 int 3 = A2;

     ^

7SegDisKeypad:17:5: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 int 4 = A3;

     ^

7SegDisKeypad:18:5: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 int 5 = 5;

     ^

7SegDisKeypad:19:5: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 int 6 = 4;

     ^

7SegDisKeypad:20:5: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 int 7 = 3;

     ^

7SegDisKeypad:21:5: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant

 int 8 = 2;

     ^

D:\GoogleDownloads\7SegDisKeypad\7SegDisKeypad.ino: In function 'void loop()':

D:\GoogleDownloads\7SegDisKeypad\7SegDisKeypad.ino:244:14: warning: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

   if (key == "1") {

              ^~~

Multiple libraries were found for "Keypad.h"
 Used: C:\Users\Spudd\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Keypad
exit status 1
expecte
```

d unqualified-id before numeric constant

This is my code:

```
#include <Keypad.h>

int E = 13;
int D = 12;
int C = 11;
int DP = 10;
int B = 9;
int A = 8;
int F = 7;
int G = 6;

int 1 == A0;
int 2 = A1;
int 3 = A2;
int 4 = A3;
int 5 = 5;
int 6 = 4;
int 7 = 3;
int 8 = 2;

const byte ROWS = 4; //four rows
const byte COLS = 4; //three columns
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {A0, A1, A2, A3}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {5,4,3,2}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void dp() {
  //High == off, LOW == On 
  digitalWrite(E, LOW);
  digitalWrite(D, LOW);
  digitalWrite(C, LOW);
  digitalWrite(DP, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(B, LOW);
  digitalWrite(A, LOW);
  digitalWrite(F, LOW);
  digitalWrite(G, LOW);
}


void one() {
  //High == off, LOW == On 
  digitalWrite(E, LOW);
  digitalWrite(D, LOW);
  digitalWrite(C, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(DP, LOW);
  digitalWrite(B, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(A, LOW);
  digitalWrite(F, LOW);
  digitalWrite(G, LOW);
}

void two() {
  //High == off, LOW == On 
  digitalWrite(E, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C, LOW);
  digitalWrite(DP, LOW);
  digitalWrite(B, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F, LOW);
  digitalWrite(G, HIGH);
}

void three() {

  digitalWrite(E, LOW);
  digitalWrite(D, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(DP, LOW);
  digitalWrite(B, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F, LOW);
  digitalWrite(G, HIGH);
}

void four() {

  digitalWrite(E, LOW);
  digitalWrite(D, LOW);
  digitalWrite(C, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(DP, LOW);
  digitalWrite(B, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(A, LOW);
  digitalWrite(F, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G, HIGH);
}

void five() {

  digitalWrite(E, LOW);
  digitalWrite(D, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(DP, LOW);
  digitalWrite(B, LOW);
  digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G, HIGH);
}

void six() {

  digitalWrite(E, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(DP, LOW);
  digitalWrite(B, LOW);
  digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G, HIGH);
}

void seven() {
  //High == off, LOW == On 
  digitalWrite(E, LOW);
  digitalWrite(D, LOW);
  digitalWrite(C, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(DP, LOW);
  digitalWrite(B, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F, LOW);
  digitalWrite(G, LOW);
}

void eight() {
  //High == off, LOW == On 
  digitalWrite(E, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(DP, LOW);
  digitalWrite(B, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G, HIGH);
}

void nine() {
  //High == off, LOW == On 
  digitalWrite(E, LOW);
  digitalWrite(D, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(DP, LOW);
  digitalWrite(B, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G, HIGH);
}

void zero() {
  //High == off, LOW == On 
  digitalWrite(E, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(DP, LOW);
  digitalWrite(B, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G, LOW);
}

void a() {
  //High == off, LOW == On 
  digitalWrite(E, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D, LOW);
  digitalWrite(C, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(DP, LOW);
  digitalWrite(B, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G, HIGH);
}
void b() {
  //High == off, LOW == On 
  digitalWrite(E, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(DP, LOW);
  digitalWrite(B, LOW);
  digitalWrite(A, LOW);
  digitalWrite(F, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G, HIGH);
}

void c() {
  //High == off, LOW == On 
  digitalWrite(E, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C, LOW);
  digitalWrite(DP, LOW);
  digitalWrite(B, LOW);
  digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(F, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(G, LOW);
}

void d() {
  //High == off, LOW == On 
  digitalWrite(E, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(D, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(C, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(DP, LOW);
  digitalWrite(B, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(A, LOW);
  digitalWrite(F, LOW);
  digitalWrite(G, HIGH);
}
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(E, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(C, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DP, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(B, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(A, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(F, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(G, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  char key = keypad.getKey();

  if (key == "1") {
    one();
  }


}
```

It appears to be some kind of error with the variables, I understand why the multiple libraries error is occurring however, I can't understand what the problem is with the other errors. It's probably just something super simple that I've missed!
Any help would be appreciated! :)
Thank you!

Comment: Variable names can't start with a number

Comment: Please don't spam tags. What does your question have to do with C#? Is the code supposed to be C or C++? Most likely C++. Use only the tags that are relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Variable names cannot start with a digit. You are trying to define variables with names starting with digits here:

```
int 1 == A0;
int 2 = A1;
int 3 = A2;
int 4 = A3;
int 5 = 5;
int 6 = 4;
int 7 = 3;
int 8 = 2;
```

Start your variable names with a letter and choose names that describes the purpose of the variable, so that a reader can understand what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're trying to have the pins on your Arduino for the number row be assigned to variables named after numbers. Try renaming them "key_0", "key_1", etc, since variables cannot start with a number. Like so,

```
int key_1 == A0;
int key_2 = A1;
int key_3 = A2;
int key_4 = A3;
```

etc..